# How to apply patches?

Tags: 7, version-control

I have installed Drupal 7 in FTP server. I am trying to apply a Drupal patch.

I did see many links online but no one shows how to do it while Drupal is in FTP server of the hosting account. I think there are many ways I can do it. One way would be to get the Net Beans. I am not sure whether I need to install Net Beans in FTP server first or install to my local machine.

If you could provide some details for beginner, it would be helpful.

Comment: Most user apply patch with [Git commands](https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/git-instructions/7.x/nonmaintainer), but you also can do it [manually](https://www.drupal.org/node/534548).

Comment: Lot of information here. Thanks. I will definitely use all of these info and try my best.

Comment: In general, it's good practice to do as little as possible on your FTP server. Try to think of your FTP server as a shopping window: you only put things there that are finished and ready to be seen by your audience. Develop your site on your local machine. Keep a copy on your local machine, preferably using a version control system like git. All software you use to do these tasks is installed locally. When you're done, push it to your web server.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on UNIX based system (e.g. MacOSX, various Linux distros), the `patch` utility is a great tool here. I typically use the command:

```
patch -p1 < patch-file.patch
```

With the `-p1` option being important for installs already under a git repo.

It sounds like your use case is a bit different though. drupal.org has a [good documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply) for applying patches in various environments.

Answer (score 3):

There is a perfect tutorial in [Applying patches with Git](https://www.drupal.org/node/1399218). There is also a simpler way to do this manually. as an example [This patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ctools-cache-handler.patch) fixes Ctools error. This is the code

```
diff --git a/includes/css-cache.inc b/includes/css-cache.inc
index d88160b..607b886 100644
--- a/includes/css-cache.inc
+++ b/includes/css-cache.inc
@@ -10,6 +10,12 @@ class CToolsCssCache implements DrupalCacheInterface {
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
+  function __construct($bin) {
+  }
+
+  /**
+   * {@inheritdoc}
+   */
 public function clear($cid = NULL, $wildcard = FALSE) {
 // Only clear the caches if the wildcard is set, this ensures that the cache
 // is only cleared when the full caches are cleared manually (eg by invoking
```

the `/includes/css-cache.inc` determines the file that needs to be modified. the `+` sign is the code that should be added and the `-` sign means the codes that need to be removed (there is non in here). so as a result in this patch, you need to look for  `public function clear($cid = NULL, $wildcard = FALSE) {` statement and insert the

```
 function __construct($bin) {
 }
```

above it. clearly this line is in `class CToolsCssCache implements DrupalCacheInterface` class.

If there is any difficulty for you to install the patch, just modify the files as I said and check if the error has gone.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the patch on your local machine using the excellent documentation mentioned above, then FTP the changed files up.

I really hope you are using some sort of versioning system somewhere during all of this. Frankly, I wouldn't accept a server setup where I was still using FTP to move around code files.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to use the [Patch Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/patch_manager) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides a developer tool for managing patches to core and contributed modules.

As a variation, here are other options to consider (mentioned on the same project page also): Possibly better solution is to use [Drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush) to apply patches (see its make command) or Drush extension [Drush Issue Queue Commands](http://drupal.org/project/drush_iq) because they don't rely on insecure configuration.